# one div to override another div

Tags: html, css

I have a div in the main of my website that i would like to over ride some of the header and hide the bottom part of the header.
in the example below, i would like the blue square the be 20px higher and hide the bottom of the header. 
i will appreciate any help.

```
<div class="header" style="height: 200px;width: 100%;background: yellow;"></div>
 <div class="main" style="height: 800px;background: orange">
  <div class="text" style="height: 100px;width: 50px;background: blue;"></div>
 </div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 .main { margin-top: -20px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.main, .text { position:relative; }
.text { top:-20px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `position` property and some `-50px margin` for your `.text`

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/uLoYaSO/1/edit)**

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="main">
    <div class="text"></div>
</div>
```

```
.header{
  position:relative;
  height: 200px;
  width:100%;
  background: yellow;
}

.main{
  position:relative;
  height: 800px;
  background: orange;
}

.text{
  position:absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
  background: blue;
  margin-top:-50px;
}
```